# Can I get masters and PhD in CSE in USA?

Tags: phd, masters, engineering

I am a student of physics at graduation level.I want to Masters and PHD in CSE in USA.
 can it possible?

Comment: You may wish to start with English spelling and grammar.

Comment: Since you are looking to change fields, I think the following question would be more useful than the duplicate one listed above: [Graduate school admission with a degree in a different field](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44651/graduate-school-admission-with-a-degree-in-a-different-field)

Comment: Suggestion for you: take TOEFL and GRE. Once you pass them, then read the question and answer Mad Jack suggested. Come back here if you still have questions.

Comment: Not to be rude. You really really need to improve your English. With your current English writing, you'll have trouble studying in the US even if you are admitted to a graduate school there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that CSE means Computational Science & Engineering, you can get a good overview of CSE graduate programs at the [SIAM webpage.](https://www.siam.org/students/resources/cse_programs.php)

Answer (score 0):

While it's not to sound rude @virmaior has a point. While you can pursue a PhD in CSE in the US, with the level of English skill you used in your questions - you need to work on your language skills before considering a PhD in the US.