# Switching Fields in Grad School

Tags: graduate-admissions

Is it Possible to switch to **Theoretical Physics** from **Chemical Engineering** ? If so,  how can i do it ?

Comment: It would help to know how far along you are in physics, and what courses, if any, you have taken in chem eng.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graduate school admission with a degree in a different field](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44651/graduate-school-admission-with-a-degree-in-a-different-field)

Comment: I am a fresher in Chemical Engineering dept.  our classes will start from 25 th of February . I am currently doing Classical mechanics from  Taylor  and Linear algebra from Strang's book .  Also i covered  some topics from  Griffits's Electrodynamics .

Comment: it would be good to add whether you are just switching departments at your same institution, or needing to change schools as well.  Also, indicate your background i theoretical physics.

Comment: i am not only switching departments but also schools.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to speak to the different departments on this. You may lose credit for the classes you have already taken in Chem. Engineering since the two fields are different. It is not "impossible", however, these two department might have different requirements for admissions, so you may not be admitted to the Theoretical Physics program. Again, best to speak to your adviser and the departments.