# Opportunities for Computer Science Graduates in the Field of Economics

Tags: phd, computer-science, career-path, changing-fields, economics

I am a cs graduate as the title suggests. I have been working as a data engineering/ science consultant for the past couple of months. And I will hopefully get a public administrative job (civil service) soon.

I am extremely interested in the field of economics and that's why I have got admitted into a masters program in economics. I am very much interested into doing research on the interface of economics and computer science and want to do a PhD in this field.

In short what I want to know is, **To what extent might I be at a disadvantage due to my CS background when I am trying to get a PhD position and then hopefully an academic position at a decent university in the field of economics or computational economics? How far will I be behind of my peers with an economics background in the overall job market if everything else on my CV is average?**

Comment: I would imagine that there are many areas of economics in which a background in CS would be a benefit rather than a drawback. Identify those areas and target your application accordingly.

Comment: Is https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44651/graduate-school-admission-with-a-degree-in-a-different-field helpful?

Answer (score 1):

PhD economics is basically an applied statistics degree in most US programs. You will not be behind your peers if you have strong understanding of math through real analysis, good understanding of matrixes and probability, and good proof-writing abilities.